# Windows Buttons extension in gnome?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, window-buttons

I want to add [Window Buttons Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/426/window-buttons/) but I could not add with gnome browser integration. On/Off slider is not working. When I slide it to ON, a dialog shows up and I select install and then nothing happens. I really want to remove title bar when window is maximized and use window buttons in status bar like this extension does.

Do you have any other suggestion for an alternative of this extension?

Or how can I install this extension manually?

- My Gnome Shell version: 3.10.4
- My Ubuntu version: 14.04.3

Comment: wait....are you trying to install gnome desktop environment add-ons to a unity desktop environment??? If you want to use this extension you'll need a gnome desktop enviroment https://ubuntugnome.org/

Comment: I installed gnome-desktop after install ubuntu 14.04.3. I am using gnome now. By the way, I could install other extensions (for example [Maximus Two](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/844/maximus-two/), [Dash-to-Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/)) before

Comment: you could install pixel saver and replace the button images manually by installing a windows style theme and changing the positions a bit with this guide https://gnomeshell.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/change-the-window-title-buttons/

Comment: It is the same situation when installing pixel-saver. I also couldn't install pixel-saver.

Comment: have you tried installing the windows buttons extension manually??

Comment: aah, I've found your problem. you are using the gnome shell version 3.10.4 and the windows buttons extension is only compatible with GNOME 3.12-3.16 according to the developers page https://github.com/danielkza/Gnome-Shell-Window-Buttons-Extension  check this guide to install 3.16 http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/upgrade-gnome-3-12-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your gnome shell to 3.12 or higher from 3.10 (!!!). Windows button extension does not support gnome shell 3.10. I however advise against upgrading to the 'experimental' desktops for beginners since it might create some glitches and bugs. If however you still want to upgrade do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/upgrade-gnome-3-12-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: thank you. I upgraded it and hid title bar using Maximus Two, Windows-Button extension together.